# .Net - call client side and server side method on click of asp:LinkButton

Tags: c#, jquery

I have an asp:LinkButton which require following -
- call jQuery to open link url in another tab of current browser
- then call server side method to perform some logging stuff

Please guide me for a

- safe (which can help avoid having 'popup blocked' messages as far as possible), I understand I shouldn't override any user personal setting for popup blocker but as it is a direct user click on asp:LinkButton, was wondering if there is a neat solution to avoid  Popup blocker messages and
- an efficient and user friendly way of calling server side method (where I can avoid postback)

Thank you!

Comment: Why not have the page that opens in the new window do the logging stuff?

Comment: becuase that is an external url, link to advertiser website.

Comment: Ah, I see. What if you had your own server-side page that the link went navigated to and then have the server redirect to the advertisers page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having Javascript make a call like:

```
window.open("http://www.google.com");
```

will always run the risk of being caught by a popup blocker.  Is there a reason why you can't just set target="_blank" on the <a> tag?

As far as calling a server-side method without doing a postback, it's not possible.  You could use JQuery's ajax function to make a call to a server side method where the page doesn't refresh, but a post-back must still occur, whether it is visible to the user or not.

Here is what that looks like:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "http://www.yourdomain.com/pageToPostTo.aspx",
  data: "your data here",
  success: function(data) {
     alert("It worked");
  },
  dataType: "json"
});
```